# Posting content from a Facebook page to a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

Is it possible to get a Facebook group to automatically show all posts from a Facebook page?

Even solutions with external apps, that only work when (the group owner/the page owner/somebody else) logs on are acceptable. This is just to save people the pain of having to post them manually.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do the following:

- Authorize a group user with `user_managed_groups` (keep in mind that he must be a group admin) and `publish_actions`.
- Create a cron job to read the [Page feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed) or (better) use the [Realtime API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/) to get the latest Page posts and post them to the group with the [group feed endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#publish).

Btw, you need a User Token for this. Extended User tokens are valid for 2 months, so you would need to refresh the token manually every 2 months.

Comment: thanks!
However... I am missing a bit of context here...
Are you talking about the facebook API?

Comment: yes, there is no other (allowed) way to post to a facebook group, you MUST use the graph api - or post manually, of course.